# updating table using datagridview

Tags: c#

could you please inform me how to display the row number of data grid view on label or text box to be able to use it in update or delete table.

I tried the following but it display nothing when i click on the data grid view cells

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();       
}
```

Comment: Can you use the SEQUENCE command in SQL to autogenerate sequential row numbers?  Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
    private void tableConteudo_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            _myObjectVar = (MyObject)table1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        }
    }
```

So, instead of using a CellContentClick, you can use CellClick event.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

```
textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

}